# How to parse song duration from media player to correct minutes in android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I call `getDuration()` method in MP Android. It returns ms value. 
For example `267180`. This value equals to `04:27`.
The question: how do I can parse convert `267180` into `04:27` programmatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Android you can use the TimeUnit functions to make conversion from milliseconds to e.g. seconds or minutes easy and human-readable.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Test
public void testFormatDuration() throws Exception {
    assertEquals("00:00", formatDuration(0));
    assertEquals("04:27", formatDuration(267180));
    assertEquals("01:00", formatDuration(60000));
    assertEquals("10:00", formatDuration(600000));
}

private String formatDuration(long duration) {
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(duration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(duration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            - minutes * TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    return String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
}
```